# UIScrollView Implementation

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

Using Storyboards, I have a UITabBarController with a UIScrollView inside, with a UIView inside the scrollView. My view is very large, and does not completely fit in the storyboard. I am not able to scroll all the way to the bottom of the View.

If you was building all of this from scratch, how would you go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a UITabBarController with 2 views. hence you have two View Controllers. Lets call  them 'A' and 'B'. Configuring two views within a tab bar controller shouldn't be too difficult if you refer to this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can achieve this using Storyboard too.

Now say, in view 'A' you want your *large* UIView within the UIScrollView. What you do is declare a UIScrollView with a framesize that is equal to the screen's dimensions but set the contentSize to your large size that you wanted. You can now have you large view within this scroll view.

Example:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 520)]; // little less than 568 to accommodate the tabBar
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1500)];
UIView *largeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 320, 100)];
[scrollView addSubview:largeView];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

You can do the above in Storyboard as well but i prefer using code for such tasks. 
Hope that helped. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `contentSize` for your scroll view? You should to set `contentSize` for scroll view to size of content view. For example if you want to show `view` in `scrollView` you should do something like this:

```
[scrollView addSubview:view]
scrollView.contentSize == view.bounds.size
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. What I ended up doing was creating a new Storyboard with a tabView already implemented. Added a new scrollView to the storyboard tabView then copied my original UIView, that I wanted to scroll in, into the scrollView.

I draged the new UIScrollView out into my .h file and created a new property.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

Then I set the new property up like so and viola!

```
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];
```