# UIScrollView The view change at run

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to implement a ScrollView, but when I put a View inside, the View looks good in the preview but it's not the same when I run the application:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZfEg.jpg

And I don't know how to resize a text of the width of the view.

Without the ScrollView I can do a good structured view but when I use ScrollView I cannot get a good view, how to do ?

Code here: http://pastebin.com/LN5FySku

Comment: @ShahzaibMaqbool The source code from StoryBoard of this view is too long, StackOverflow wont to post it

Comment: check my answer i think this helped you ... pardon me if i post wrong answer but i think this is what you want..

Comment: @ShahzaibMaqbool I did a pastebin http://pastebin.com/LN5FySku sorry for late, I didn't put Swift code, I only did it with the Storyboard

Answer (score 0):

I think this task is very easy if you use code rather than storyboard.
Use this code..

You can do this in Storyboard as well but i prefer using code for such tasks. Hope that helped.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 520)]; // little less than 568 to accommodate the tabBar
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1500)];
UIView *largeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 320, 100)];
[scrollView addSubview:largeView];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

for further more information check this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758024/uiscrollview-implementation).

Comment: you should not copy paste answers from link. just comment this link. and he use autolayout. Please check image.

Comment: My problem was from the ImageView, they was loaded in the preview but on Storyboard the field image was empty like if I haven't chose an image, so it's good but my problem now is the text, the width is not good, the text is cropped, how to do ?

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani I found the problem for the imageView take a look on my previous response, but I still have a problem with my text, do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved, the reasons:

UIImageView: I think my view have lost the images when i did a copy past of the view, so click on your UIImageView and set the image field.

UILabel: For the cropped text you have to create the Equal Width Constraint between the ContentView and the View, select the ContentView on the view hierarchy and Control + Drag to the View – you should get a pop-up that gives you the “Equal Widths” option.